# Laravel Odd POST behaviour

Tags: php, post, laravel

I'm setting up a Payment Portal in Laravel 4, connecting to SagePay using Server Integration.

The checkout connects to SagePay without any problems, but after the user has entered their card details and is returned to the website I'm having trouble reading the response from SagePay,

SagePay are sending a POST request to one of my pages, but Laravel will only display the page if I route::GET request (route::POST returns HttpMethodNotAllowed) and none of the POST data is received.

How can Laravel be reading the request as GET when it is POST?

I have tried Route::any but this still has no POST data,

```
Route::post('cardpayment/result', array('uses'=>'CartController@postSageResult'));

public function postSageResult() {
   $data = Input::all();            
   Log::info('data:'.var_dump($data));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Route::post`? Do you know what URL they are POSTing to? I imagine it's the same URL that sent the request to them.

Comment: yes I get HTTPmethodNotAllowed Error, I define the notification url, and both my logs and thiers show it finds the page ok

Comment: Show the code from that attempt.

Comment: Are you sure SagePay is POSTing to you? Are you hosting this locally?

Comment: Hosting Live, and they assure me they are POSTing the data

Comment: You don't have any other routes which could be responding to that request could you?

Comment: Wait, are you expecting to see a page when SagePay sends a POST request to you? That's not how it works.

Comment: No, at the moment I just want to store the POST data to the log so I know its there, eventually I will be returning a string with the re-direct data on it.

Comment: No other routes with the same name either

Comment: The logger takes an array of information as a second argument and will format it nicely for you.  var_dump may be what's causing the issue of you not seeing the request.  Try `Log::info('SavePay post data', $data)`

Comment: "ventually I will be returning a string with the re-direct data on it." - this does not make sense. The POST request has nothing to do with the user's session or where he's redirected.

Comment: I was literally just about to mention that var_dump() might be what's causing it. var_dump() outputs the data, it doesn't return a string of the data for you.

Comment: Use `var_export` for that, but `Log` is supposed to take care of that.

Comment: @user3158900 Tried that but got this: [2015-01-08 13:55:12] production.INFO: SavePay post data [] []

Comment: The problem must be within the routing somewhere, if I create a Route::get, there is no Method no allowed Error, and the page loads as expected, if i use Route::post there is an error, but Sagepay assure me they are posting the data, so I'm confussed

Comment: Did you read my answer? There *should be no GET route*. You are not supposed to access the URL that way. A POST Route _should_ NOT be accessible through a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `HTTPmethodNotAllowed` when trying to GET a route that's set as POST? That's exactly how it should work. SagePay is supposed to send the POST request to you.

- "Laravel will only display the page if I route as a GET request" - this is normal. When opening a URL in a browser it automatically sends a GET request to that URL. If you define a `Route::post` Laravel won't serve anything on a GET request, except the obvious `HTTPmethodNotAllowed` exception.
- "and none of the POST data is displaying" - what POST data? You are sending a GET request when accessing the page through a browser.

Here's how this whole secure payment gateway works:

1) GET request on your website for a form

2) User fills in the form with some data (NOT Credit Card data!)

3) Using the SagePay API you redirect the user to a page on *SagePay.com*.

4) Here the user fills in Credit Card data. This page has absolutely no connection to *your website*.

5) The user submits the SagePay form. He is told that his transaction will be processed and he is redirected back to a page on your website. You are not yet supposed to treat this transaction as processed. You have to wait for SagePay to *confirm* this. And it will, by sending that POST request...

*Some Magick happens here*. It could take 1 second or 1 day. There is no way you can control that.

6) SagePay processes the request (talks with the banks, etc.). If the transaction succeeds then SagePay will make a POST request to *your website* at that `Route::post` route you've configured. Here you'll have access to `$data = Input::all();` which most likely will contain some details about the transaction that just occurred. Most likely in step (3) you sent a unique ID to SagePay. This unique ID will be present in `$data` so that you know *what* transaction succeeded.

Comment: Thank you Sergiu, but the problem is I'm getting a HTTPmethodNotAllowed when trying Route::post, it only seems to work with Route::get but there is no POST data with this.

Comment: But _HOW_ are you trying to send that POST request? If you are trying to open the URL in a browser window then that sends a GET request, not a POST request. And obviously there is no POST data associated with a GET request. That would make zero sense. And again, _WHY_ are you trying to access that route? SagePay is supposed to access it, not yourself.

Comment: effectively I'm at step six in your breakdown, waiting for the response from SagePay, they are sending a POST containing the results of the transaction. 
They expect me to output a string like: 
"STATUS:OK VendorTxCode:12345 Redirect:www.website.com" the VendorTxCode is part of the post data so I need to read this first. Currently when I create a Route::post and try to collect this data I get the httpnotallowederror. The only way I've been able to avoid this error is by switching to route::get, this activates the code on the page but because there is no post data the field end up blank.

Comment: Does `Log::info('data:'.var_export($data, true));` work?

Comment: just an empty array: [2015-01-08 14:27:11] production.INFO: data:array () [] []

Comment: Are they maybe sending data as POST _body_? Try `$request = Request::instance();

Log::info('data:'.var_export($request->getContent(), true));`

Comment: empty string this time: [2015-01-08 14:32:00] production.INFO: data:'' [] [].

Comment: But...you are testing this by actually having SagePay send a POST request to you, right? Just read the docs, `Input:all` should work.

Comment: yep, running through test purchases, I'm setting up a script outside the framework to ensure the data is being sent, it'll take some time to build but might point to a solution

Comment: I have a problem with post request too. Can you please help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113117/post-request-not-working-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

well its still behaving as a GET request but I'm at least able to get the POST data using

```
public function postSageResult() {
   $get_dump = print_r($_POST, true); 
   Log::info('data:'.$get_dump);
```

Apprechiate anyone explaining why this works when Var_dump, var_export, Request::instance() & Input::all() all failed

Comment: "still behaving as a GET request" - this makes no sense

Comment: I have a problem with post request too. Can you please help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113117/post-request-not-working-laravel-5)